# horizontal line segments

Tags: r, ggplot2

int_times

```
gene       lag     stim num
 a1  46.53000 173.5300   1
 a2 101.47000 162.5900   2
 a3  14.00000 259.0000   3
 a4   6.43276 134.1821   4
 a5  28.00000 182.0000   5
 a6  16.00000 198.0000   6
```

here's my gg code

```
   ggplot(int_times,aes(x=stim,y= num,colour=gene)) +
       scale_y_continuous(labels=c('should not exist',int_times$gene)) +
       # geom_line(aes(position)) +
       geom_segment(aes(xend=length(stim),yend=.01)) +
       xlab('x') +
       ylab('y') +          
       opts(title = 'Multiple Gs')
```

i can't figure out how to get hline to work, but I would like every thing the way it is now, except for each line to be a separate horizontal segment on it's corresponding y axis
[image]

Comment: think about what you need to make a segment.  You need two points each with an x and a y coordinate.  You've given 2 coordinates when 4 are needed.  You have to give yend and ystart the factor levels.

Comment: yeah Doug, I struggled with this guy too when i first started, check out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how this works for you:

```
   ggplot(int_times,aes(x=stim,y=gene ,colour=gene)) +
       geom_segment(aes(xend=length(stim),ystart=gene, yend=gene)) +
       xlab('x') +
       ylab('y') +          
       opts(title = 'Multiple Gs')
```

Doug I edited and supplied y with genes as this seems to be what you want on the y axis anyway.

Comment: @Doug you may not always be plotting horizontally, Wickham is providing the tools to do anything (well most anything) but you have to figure out how the grammar of the graphic works.

Comment: Doug if you supply `y` the genes instead of num (as that seems to be what you want on the y axis anyway) then you only have to supply a start or end y.